# SQL: Inner JOIN statement doesn't give the right records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

With the SQL below, I am trying to record all matching rows from the right table "order_flags".

```
 SELECT id, 
        po_number, 
        alert 
 FROM orders 
 INNER JOIN order_flags on order_flags.order_fk 
 WHERE order_flags.alert = " date("Y-m-d") . "
 AND order_flags.order_fk = orders.id 
 AND orders.flag_overdue_po='1';
```

The tables are as below. First one is orders table while the second order_flags table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The `on` clause of a join is supposed to contain some sort of comparison e.g. `on users.department_id = departments.id` or similar. Yours just contains a one-sided expression so it'll probably always evaluate to true. Revise your understanding of JOINs and look at some examples.

Comment: " date("Y-m-d") . " - I can't even guess what was intended by this -

Comment: Maybe ` order_flags.order_fk = orders.id` should be the join condition ?

Comment: @P.Salmon true. Maybe a botched attempt to put some PHP into the string. I've just removed the PHP tag, although now you've pointed that out, perhaps there was a reason for it. No reason they couldn't just generate the date using SQL though.

Comment: `SELECT id, 
        po_number, 
        alert 
 FROM orders 
 INNER JOIN order_flags on order_flags.order_fk = orders.id
 WHERE order_flags.alert = 'your date'
 AND orders.flag_overdue_po='1';`

Comment: In shown structure this `on order_flags.order_fk` joining expression simply checks that this column value is not zero or NULL. After ignoring such rows all another rows are cross-joined with first table. Do you need in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't investigate further but your ON-statement does only contain one value. It needs the two matching columns of your two tables like

```
ON table1.column_id = table2.column_id
```

Comment: Incorrect in general. `ON clause` expression must return scalar value which can be treated as boolean, and not more. No other restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

if you not sure the related record must exist in `order_flags`,please use left join.The sql maybe

```
SELECT id, 
        po_number, 
        alert 
 FROM orders 
 LEFT JOIN order_flags on order_flags.order_fk = orders.id
 WHERE order_flags.alert = " date("Y-m-d") . "
 AND orders.flag_overdue_po='1';
```